# Smooth scrolling Textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView, defined like this:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/play_info"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/play_info_background"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:maxLines="8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textColor="@color/play_info_text_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/play_info_font_size"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >
    </TextView>
```

I set the TextView to be scrollable in code, like this:

```
cardInfo = (TextView) play.findViewById(R.id.play_info);
cardInfo.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

The TextView scrolls, but not smoothly, like anything inside a ScrollView.
I would like for it to scroll smoothly.

I have already tried putting the TextView (with scrolling disabled) inside a ScrollView, but this messes with the height of the TableRow it's contained in, and there doesn't seem to be a way to correct that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if you want "smooth scroll" you have to place the `TextView` in a `ScrollView`. And when you do that, you can no longer
set the height of the `TextView` to "match_parent". Like, for example, when you need a large TextBox that is filled dynamically with text,
but not resized. And when you try by setting the `ScrollView`'s attribute to "match_parent", the child `TextView` still wraps around the content.

I was able to do it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:typeface="serif"/>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

A `RelativeLayout` container that serves as a new `TextView`, with the desired background, the original `TextView` with background set to null. So when the TextView
expands, with new text appended, it's just like text volume increasing. The text is aligned with the layout attributes if the `ScrollView`.

You may also need to disable scrolling for the `TextView`, to avoid collision with the `ScrollView`'s scrolling in certain scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

You probably missing focus attribute, Textview is not in focus so its not scrolling.

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title_itemcount"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
     android:maxLines="3"
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:scrollbars="vertical"
     android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
```

Hope it helps... :)

Comment: focus attribute Not helped :(